# Salt Stack: Function: pkg.installed. Yum does not update installed package

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, salt-stack

My code is:

```
others:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - epel-release: https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
      - salt-latest: https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm
```

and I'm getting error:

```
errors:
    - Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
      Setting up Install Process
      Examining     /var/cache/salt/minion/extrn_files/base/repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm: salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch
      /var/cache/salt/minion/extrn_files/base/repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
      Error: Nothing to do
```

I thinkt that may be a problem with **salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm**. When I manually run yum install for this RPM's I'm getting the same error but running in Salt Stack only getting this error.

It should end with:

```
      ID: others
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: True
 Comment: All specified packages are already installed
 Started: 10:45:33.171971
Duration: 595.672 ms
 Changes:
```

but I'm getting:

```
      ID: others
Function: pkg.installed
  Result: False
 Comment: Error occurred installing package(s). Additional info follows:

          errors:
              - Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
                Setting up Install Process
                Examining /var/cache/salt/minion/extrn_files/base/repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm: salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch
                /var/cache/salt/minion/extrn_files/base/repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
                Error: Nothing to do
 Started: 10:46:13.906581
Duration: 8988.515 ms
 Changes:
```

Comment: have you done a `yum clean all` and retried?

Comment: Can you open an issue on github about this?

Comment: [41634](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/41634)

Answer (score 0):

The package name is salt-repo not salt-latest.

Code should be:

```
others:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - epel-release: https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-5.noarch.rpm
      - salt-repo: https://repo.saltstack.com/yum/redhat/salt-repo-latest-2.el6.noarch.rpm
```